# My function is not printing the modified variable inside it

Tags: python, function, variables

The code is printing the original starting balance of 5000 instead of the modified balance 4900 in the function.

```
def Building(mon, house, office):
  print("A house costs 100 dollars and an office does too")
  building_type = input("House or office?: ")
  if building_type == "House":
    print("You have built your first building, a house!")
    mon -= 100
    house += 1
  elif building_type == "Office":
    print("You have constructed an office in your city!")
    mon -= 100
    office += 1
  else:
    print("Neither house or office was entered, enter again.")
    Building(mon, house, office)

Building(money, houses, offices)
print(money)
```

Comment: Your code never returns any values nor does the function call assign the return value a name.

Comment: `int` is called by _value_. Modification of `int` parameter inside a method will not modify the variable in the scope of the caller function. i.e. although you are modifying `mon` in `Building`, the `money` variable (outside `Building`) will not be modified. If you want the modified value, `return mon` from the `Building` and assign that to `money`.

Comment: @mshsayem since I'm new to python some of that made sense to me but just for clarification how would I go about assigning that? Would I return mon in Building and then say money = Building(parameters). Because when  I do that it calls the function and then requires input from the user which I don't always want. This has been happening with all my functions where I want to use variables both in and out of a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return the variable mon.

```
if building_type=="House":
    # do calculations
    return (mon, house, office)

elif building_type=="Office":
    # do calculations
    return (mon, house, office)
```

and then

```
results = Building(money, house, office)
print(results[0]) # for money
print(results[1]) # for house
print(results[2]) # for office
```

Comment: That worked thanks alot! Also what about with offices would I do the same thing? But it comes up with 'unreachable code error'. As with money it didn't?                                                                                                            elif building_type == "Office":
      print("You have constructed an office in your city!")
      mon -= 100
      office += 1
      return mon
      return office

Comment: Hi @CrisYabaro just need help with the below code, I was readressing the money variable and it didn't work: 
def Check(change, income, balance):
       if change == 3:
           print("More money to you! Weekly income...")
           balance += income
           print("You now have %s dollars" % balance)
           return balance
      else:
           balance = balance
           print("It hasn't been a week yet.")
          return balance
weekincome = Check(major_weekly_changes, rent, money)
money = weekincome[2]
print(money)

Comment: Apparently, 'int' object is not suscriptable. Pretty much my conclusion to my question is how do I use a variable in and out of functions because I will want to add rent to the user's balance and other things to the balance in and out of functions. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @Greta, since you're just returning the value of the variable "balance" , which is an integer type, you can write it just like this money = Check(major_weekly_changes, rent, money). If your function Check returns a tuple or a list, then you would use weekincome[index].